# Programmatically end outgoing/incoming calls using custom onClick event in Android API level 30 or higher using Java

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application where I need to programmatically end outgoing or incoming calls using a custom onClick event. I have tried several approaches, but I have not been able to find a reliable solution.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
close_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Retrieve the activity context
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    try {
                        Class<?> c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                        m.setAccessible(true);
                        ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);

                        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                        if (bundle != null) {
                            String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
                            Log.d("INCOMING", phoneNumber);
                            if (phoneNumber != null) {
                                telephonyService.endCall();
                                Log.d("HANG UP", phoneNumber);
                            }
                        }
                        CustomDialog.this.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.SlidingDialogAnimation;
                        CustomDialog.this.finishAndRemoveTask();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

However, I keep encountering issues such as "NoSuchMethodException" or "MethodNotFound" when attempting to access hidden methods like getITelephony().

Exception:

> Accessing hidden method Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getITelephony()Lcom/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony; (greylist-max-p, reflection, denied)
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getITelephony []
> java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
> java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
> app.rsn.rb.call.CustomDialog$1.onClick(CustomDialog.java:137)I have thoroughly researched the official Android SDK documentation, but I have not found any supported method to achieve call control programmatically.

Could someone please provide guidance or suggest alternative approaches to programmatically end outgoing or incoming calls using a custom onClick event in Android Java?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to either implement a full blown dialer replacement app that is chosen by the user as the default or at least implement a CallScreeningService (which also has to be chosen as the default). All tricks like reflection / mocking headset button presses to pickup/decline/end calls were culled by the android team so all answers that you found that suggested that are outdated and won't work unless you're running app on a really old device.

Comment: Hi Pawel, 
Thank you for your response and clarification. I understand that call control methods using reflection or other tricks are no longer viable on newer Android versions. I'll explore alternative approaches within the allowed framework.